# Airflow on WSL2 Ubuntu: ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'

Tags: windows, ubuntu, airflow, wsl-2

I am aware that very similar questions have been asked previously but I have found these have tended to include Docker, which I am not using at this time, nor do I have installed. I am led to believe that WSL2 should be an alternative to Docker regarding running Airflow on Windows.

I am using WSL2 on my Windows 11 laptop and have installed Apache-Airflow from a tutorial from the following link:
https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2018/11/06/apache-airflow-windows-10-install-ubuntu/

On WSL2 I have:

- Python version 3.8.10
- Pip version 20.0.2
- Apache-Airflow 2.4.1 (I believe)

I have run the following commands (as per the tutorial) with no issue:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install apache-airflow   #I had path issues without 'sudo' command
```

But when I attempt to use the 'airflow' command in the WSL2 Ubuntu terminal, I am greeted with the following error:

```
$ airflow
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 563, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 744, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.filename_template, self.filename_jinja_template = parse_template_string(filename_template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py", line 165, in parse_template_string
    import jinja2
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/nodes.py", line 23, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 656, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 564, in initialize
    LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
    dictConfig(logging_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 570, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'
```

I have googled the ValueError extensively and can't find any clear solutions that don't involve Docker.

Any insight into the error would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is the version of markupsafe ?

Comment: I believe my markupsafe is version 2.1.1.
I get this when installing apache-airflow:
"Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.1.1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install airflow using constraints.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#installation-tools

This is the only way installation of airflow is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you, Jarek!
I uninstalled apache-airflow and reinstalled following the advice from the link you provided and it seems to be working fine now.